# Making global helper functions in a php mvc

Tags: php

I have been following a tutorial to develop a mvc  using php.
In the framework all the configuration settings are stored in a `Config.php(Config class)` under `App` namespace. The properties are constant so If I want to access a property, I have to *use the namespace first* anywhere I want to access it. So now I can access it like below

`Config::DB_NAME` OR `Config::DB_HOST`

So, **Is there any way I can define a global helper function say `config()` using which I can access those values?**
Say, If I want to access `DB_NAME` , I would type`config('DB_NAME')`

Also, If I want to define some other global helper functions, How can make it?

To make the question more clear. Take Laravel's hleper functions. There is a helper function `config()` which returns a value from various configuration files. Like `config('app.name')` will return the APP Name.
These helper functions can be accessed from anywhere, Vies, Models, and Controllers.

Here is what I think can be done.

I don't want to group the functions in a class, that way I have to use namespaces.
Maybe, I can use traits to group the functions. 
But How to make it available in each class. I can use `use Helpers`, but then

How would I access the function from a view file which doesn't have a classs?

Any, idea or suggestion would be helpful.

**Config.php**

```
<?php
  namespace App;

  class Config
  {
     const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
     const DB_NAME = 'mvc';
     const DB_USER = 'root';
     const DB_PASSWORD = '';
     const SHOW_ERRORS = false;
   }
```

The project is currently on github, If anyone want a look of the files structure can see [here](https://github.com/Lordofcodes/PHP-MVC/blob/master/App/Config.php)
**Edit**
Maybe I can have `config.php` file which just returns an associative array.
Yet I need a helper function to get the values from it. The file would be like this.

```
<?php

 return [
       'DB_HOST'=>'localhost',
        'DB_NAME'=>'mvc',
       'DB_USERNAME'=>'root',
       'DB_PASSWORD' =>'',
        ];
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way, but in my projects I often have a `functions.php` file where I define all my "global" functions. Then every file in the project starts with `include('functions.php')`. Or if I already have a file that is included at the top of every file (like auth.php for verifying login status), I just put the `include('functions.php')` in that

Comment: @Stevish Of course, that's a way.  Maybe there  is some other way, because Laravel does that, so there must be some other concept that I don't know.

Comment: In a proper way of OOP you'll never need any global functions - There is no reason for having global functions

Comment: @B001ᛦ If I have a `config.php` file where there is information about the owner of the app and I want to access it in my view. How would I do that? Or I want check if a user is authenticated or not in my view file, How would I do that ? 
I don't think using namespaces and classes would a good idea in a view file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you solve multiple environments, like local, staging, prod, testing etc when you hard code the values as constants directly into your config-class?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't want it hard code in a cofig class. That's the way it has been done. I want to know if there is some other way? Maybe using a global helper to access configuration values.

Comment: As people already mentioned, if you build your framework using best practices (like dependency injection, separation of concern, kiss, dry and what not), you should never need to create global helpers. Then you should create a class that loads a config-file (like a PHP-array, yaml, json or similar) and populate the config values from that. There are plenty of config-classes on packagist. Look how they are doing it ti get some ideas. Here's an example: https://github.com/magnus-eriksson/config. That code should be fairly easy to understand and follow.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I really appreciate your support, maybe, studying that package I would find a way or learn something new from it that would lead me to find a  way.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at existing PHP frameworks and see how they handle it. Laravel is a good example.

Comment: Don't just look at one. Look at a few different ones and see different ways people are doing it. There's multiple ways to skin this cat (it's an expression, I'm not advocating actually skinning cats).

Comment: @BramVerstraten - In my opinion, Laravel might be a bit too complex to start with. There are so many things going on behind the scenes. It's basically PHP's version of Ruby On Rails :-p

Comment: I thank all of you, I will definitely try and find a way and maybe I would be able to  skin this cat. And I agree, Laravel is a bit complex, I already tried but couldn't skin that cat.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I found a way, and it's working for now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to  you all for your help and support.*

I, finally, found a solution. It's working and good for now. Maybe there is some other way but It will work for me for now.
Here are the steps that I followed to solve it.

Defined all my configuration setting in a separate file called `Configs.php` This file just returns an associative array.

**Configs.php**

```
 <?php

  return [

      'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
      'DB_NAME' => 'mvc',
      'DB_USER' => 'root',
      'DB_PASSWORD' => '',

      'SHOW_ERRORS' => false
       ];
```

I used composer to autoload my `Helpers.php` file. *I didn't give it any namespace so it is globally loaded.*

**Helpers.php *(OLD)***

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('config')) {
   function config($key)
   {
      $config_array = include 'Configs.php';

      if (array_key_exists($key,$config_array))
      {
           return $config_array[$key];
       }
     }
 }
```

**Helpers.php *(Updated - Suggested by Magnus Erikkson)***

```
<?php

  if (!function_exists('config')) {
    function config($key, $fallback = null)
    {
         static $config;

         if (is_null($config)) {
             $config = include 'Configs.php';
             }

     return array_key_exists($key, $config)
        ? $config[$key]
        : $fallback;
 }
```

}
*Both files `Config.php` and `Helpers.php` are under App directory*
and here is **composer.json**

```
{
"require": {
    "twig/twig": "^2.0",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
},
"autoload": {

    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Core\\":"Core/",
        "App\\":"App/"

    }
   }
  }
```

**Now, I can access it in my controller like `config('DB_NAME')` and it is working!**

Comment: Your current function will include the config file everytime you call that function. That gives you a massive overhead if you call the function many times.  This can very easily be solved using [static variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static). I modified your config-function to show an example: https://3v4l.org/uWvkv.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks a lot, I didn't notice. I will update the answer So that I could keep it as a reference in future. Thanks again. That was really an issue I didn't think of.

Comment: You should also accept your answer so others know the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I can't accept it today, it says :)